# Can I somehow check the supply of an ally in a team game?

Tags: starcraft-2

Lets say I am in a 2v2 team game. There are two situations in which I want to check an ally's supply.

- He has left and I have to macro for him. When should I add new Supply Depots (or Pylons or Overlords)?
- I am nearly maxed and want to push. I want to see how much supply he has, so I can decide if it is beneficial to wait or to push immediately.

In the second scenario I could ask him, but in the first I have to guess.

Is there a way to check the supply of an ally during the game?

Comment: Pretty sure it's a no.

Comment: Was about to say the same @Decency, only thing I know you can do is get the "not enough supply" response once you hit cap.

Comment: I looked into this and found those two threads: http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/708342190 and http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=135980 . Neither has a solution. It seems this is a known problem, but Blizzard does not address it.

Comment: [This post](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewpost.php?post_id=15824560) sais: "if you click on an ally's unit in a teamgame (after he's left) the indicator in the top right will show his supply count, rather than yours." But it does not work for me. Can anyone test if this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, on the ladder there is no way to check your allies supply when he leaves. You will hear notifications of being supply blocked, however. Unfortunately this makes it very hard for  a player to macro for both players.